# Why does my eventlistener for input search doesnt work?

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I am working on an application to search for cities. It returns a card with the flag, capital, population and region; however, it works only until I try to add an `eventListener` to the input search, after which, it does nothing.

Am I calling the search incorrectly? should I maybe do a search function?

P. S: I started coding ~6 months ago and sorry if it is a not well-constructed code.

```js
const APICALL = 'https://restcountries.eu/rest/v2/';
const form = document.querySelector('.recherche')
const input = document.querySelector('.inpRecherche');
const searchBtn = document.querySelector('.searchBtn');
const affichage = document.querySelector('.affichage');


let cities = [];


//API call 

async function dataApi(cities) {

  const call = await fetch(APICALL);
  const data = await call.json();
  cities = data;
  //console.log(cities);

  createCard(cities);

}
dataApi(cities)



function createCard(cities) {

  for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {

    const cardHTML = `
    <div class="carte">
        <img src="${[cities[i].flag]}" alt="flag"   class="avatar">
        <h2>${[cities[i].name]}</h2>
        <ul class="cont-infos">
            <li class="capital">Capital : ${[cities[i].capital]}</li>
            <li class="population">Population: ${[cities[i].population]}</li>
            <li class="subregion">Region : ${[cities[i].subregion]}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    `;
    affichage.innerHTML = cardHTML;
  }
}
searchBtn.addEventListener('click', dataApi);
form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()

  if (e.value > 0) {
    //console.log('hello');
    dataApi([cities[i]]);
    input.value = "";
  }
})
```

```css
*,
 ::before,
 ::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("Background.jpg");
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-size: cover;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 30px;
}

.inpRecherche {
  display: block;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 3px;
  font-size: 12px;
}

form,
.affichage {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.affichage {
  position: absolute;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 20px 480px;
}

.searchBtn {
  height: 25px;
  padding: 2px 5px;
  background-color: #2896F6;
  box-shadow: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: whitesmoke;
  font-weight: bold;
  border-radius: 3px solid white;
}

.searchBtn:hover {
  background-color: #167CD4;
}


/* a partir d'ici c'est à créer
    */

.card {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 200px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: beige;
}

.avatar {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin-top: 80px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25px;
}

.cont-infos {
  border-top: 1px dashed black;
  margin-top: 20px;
  list-style-type: none;
}

li {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: 22px;
}

li:nth-child(1) {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h1>City finder </h1>

<form class="recherche">
  <input type="text" class="inpRecherche" placeholder="Rechercher une ville">
  <button class="searchBtn">Chercher</button>

</form>

<div class="affichage">

</div>
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on what does "*it does work until..*" exactly mean? what's not working afterwards?

Comment: i mean that the code runs i do have a flag, a capital, population etc when i search manually

Comment: The submit function makes no sense, sure why you have that and also he button click.

Comment: that's what i thought U_U i will try again :) thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi Lizeth and welcome to StackOverflow.
I'm not completely sure of what you are trying to do, but right now, your function `createCard` is not looping over all the cities you receive from the API, but writing over and over the content of `cardHTML`. To display all the cities, you can add a `+`in front of the `=` and

```js
function createCard(cities) {
  for (let i = 0; i < cities.length; i++) {
    const cardHTML = `
    <div class="carte">
        <img src="${[cities[i].flag]}" alt="flag"   class="avatar">
        <h2>${[cities[i].name]}</h2>
        <ul class="cont-infos">
            <li class="capital">Capital : ${[cities[i].capital]}</li>
            <li class="population">Population: ${[cities[i].population]}</li>
            <li class="subregion">Region : ${[cities[i].subregion]}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    `;
    affichage.innerHTML += cardHTML;
  }
}
```

And change your css classes to

```css
.affichage {
  justify-content: center;
  border: 2px solid whitesmoke;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 90vw;
  height: auto;
  margin: 20px auto 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.avatar {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: initial;
  background-color: #000;
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

But, be warned,  building html this way can be very dangerous, see [XSS attacks](https://medium.com/spidernitt/xss-for-dummies-eeb1a4133e52).

And to search for a city using the input, Yes, you need to build a search function yourself, and display the result. [Regex](https://regex101.com/) could be a way to do it

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to my attention is the argument you're passing to the dataApi function. When you pass it to the event listener, the [argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#the_event_listener_callback) it receives is an `event` object (you're just naming it "cities"), and then you're trying to overwrite it with data from the API call instead of updating the global `cities` array.